# Remove Duplicate Words from input string. Use VBA Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Language: **VBA**
Environment: **Excel 2007**
Tool: **RegEx object**

Hi! I'm trying to remove duplicate words from input string that represent an address.
I receive an excel worksheet column with somehow combined address pieces. It is not in Cyrillic, but if to represent in English it'll look something like this:

```
125424, RepeatedName, RepeatedName, and some words, 75
194044, Repeated-dashedName, Repeated-dashedName, other Uniques, 3
300911, Normal non-repeated, names, dashed and non-Dashed, 123
```

The text is case-insensitive and can contain numbers, punctuation marks, spaces. It is known that duplicate words can only appear one exactly after another, there will not be other "exclusive" word among duplicate instances except comas and spaces.
I need to remove duplicate dashed and non-dashed words and keep only single instance if each repeated word. I need to keep the only instance of "**RepeatedName**" same as "**Repeated-dashedName**". So the ideal result will look like this:

```
125424, RepeatedName, and some words, 75
194044, Repeated-dashedName, other Uniques, 3
300911, Normal non-repeated, names, dashed and non-Dashed, 123
```

To solve this I've tried different variants of code, but working one is escaping from me. My best guess is this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim strIn As String, strPattern As String, strReplace As String, strResult as String
dim regex As Object

strIn = fnGetInputString()
strPattern = ".*\b((\w+)\b.*\1).*"
strReplace = "$1"

If regex Is Nothing Then Set regex = New RegExp

With regex
  .MultiLine = False
  .Global = True
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Pattern = strPattern
End With

strResult = regex.Replace(strIn, strReplace)
```

but as a result, my strResult consequently gave me only this:

```
75
3
123
```

So I haven't managed to correctly capture and reuse repeated group in the regex.
Any help will be appreciated.

I'm new to regex but have read some documentation, articles, discussions and StackOverflow questions, but have found no working answer.

Comment: Can we have a case like `125424, RepeatedName, someOtherWord, RepeatedName, and some words, 75` where the repeatedName's second instance can be anywhere in the string(i.e, not just after the 1st instance)?

Comment: The possibility of this is not zero, but near that. We can ignore those cases.

Answer (score 3):

This regex works on the example:

```
\b([a-zA-Z-]+)[^a-zA-Z-]+\1\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7hLyit/1/)

Essentially, works like so:

```
\b([a-zA-Z-]+)[^a-zA-Z-]+\1\b
 ^                          ^      assert a word boundary
   ^   ^   ^ ^                     capture a 'word' series of characters
                ^                  separated by non 'word' characters
                         ^         where the captured word is then repeated
```

The character set `[a-zA-Z-]` is limited to the ASCII sense of a 'letter' plus a dash. (Make sure the `-` is at the END of the character class or else you are defining a range.)

For non latin or non-ASCII character sets, you can either use `\p{L}` in more modern regex engines or reverse the sense of a 'word' by excluding what a word is not:

```
\b([^ ,]+)[ ,]+\1\b

     ^                    a word is not a space or a comma...
            ^             a word delimiter is a space or comma...
```

That works even in basic regex engines such as `sed`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wYoSnn/2/)

Comment: dawg, thank you for your answer. I understand the logic and mechanics. I've tested it in English-and-Cyrillic combination in the input string. It would work only in English duplicates search-and-replace. Despite even that I've typed in the whole my alphabet letter by letter in both lower and upper cases additionally to your given English letters ranges.

Comment: So I suspect the problem might have something to encoding or something else.

Comment: If excel supports it, use the meta character for 'letter' of `\p{L}`

Comment: I've tried to put 
 strPattern = "\b([\p{L}-]+)[^\p{L}-]+\1\b"
but 
 regex.Test(strIn)
returned to me "False". So, I think that excel VBA regex does not support meta character \p{L}.

Comment: You can also do `\b([^ ,]+)[ ,]+\1\b` to capture non-space, non-comma followed by space or comma. That should pick up non-ascii characters. The general scheme is the same: `X+` is a word, `[^X]+`is not, followed by a repeat of `X+`  Just play with the character sets to capture and the negation of that set to delimit then refer back to what is captured.

Comment: This pattern also failed for me. After beating the wall by my head, I've discovered that only Unicode characters would work for me.
The final version is like strPattern = "([\u0400-\u04FF-]+)[ ,]*\1". It fits my case because I need to work with this Unicode page symbols only.
Dawg, thank you one more time! You gave me the correct direction, that helped to find the decision.

Comment: In my case, excel-VBA somehow did not correctly recognize metacharacters \b and \w. So I had to abandon them, though it's not strictly correct.